# after upgrade to 3.6 error time zone

Tags: joomla-2.5, date, joomla-3.6

After migrating from Joomla 2.5 to 3.6, I get the following error on the homepage:

> DateTimeZone::__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone (0)

Does anyone know how I can overcome this?

Comment: Which version of PHP you are using there?

Comment: I am Using 5.5.12 @pl71

Comment: What you have in Global Configuration/Server/ Location Settings/Time Zone? Try to change here and advise results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just disable module called mod_highlighter_gk4 . 
that Solved my problem .

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jEvents or any other extension that works heavily with dates? If  yes, then your solution could be by changing the timezone in the configuration of jEvents (or the other extension that you're using) to a "recognized" timezone. Try switching to a well know timezone first and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Dear @itoctopus 
I am not using Jevents ..
and I changed Time Configuration . That not working   also . 
any Ideas ?